# How do I reuse this JavaScript timeout closure?

Tags: javascript, timeout, closures, settimeout

I found the following piece of JavaScript code (maybe here at Stack Overflow?) for implementing a timeout:

```
var delay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

I'm new to JavaScript, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around closures. If I call `delay(firstCallback, 200)` in one place and then `delay(secondCallback, 200)` right after, the first timeout callback is cleared, while the second callback executes successfully.

How do I reuse `delay` in different instances without overwriting other instances? (Not sure if those terms are correct, but hopefully it gets my point across.) So, in the above example, I want both callbacks to execute.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: As a practical example, I'm trying to buffer keypress events on an input field, so that the callback is only executed after no key has been pressed for 200ms. But I have multiple input fields, and currently the buffer breaks when two input fields have keypress events in quick succession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reuse this, it is easier to get rid of the anonymous function and use it as a generator.

```
var createDelayManager = function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
}


var delayManagerOne = createDelayManager();
delayManagerOne(firstCallback, 200);

var delayManagerTwo = createDelayManager();
delayManagerTwo(secondCallback, 200);
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HJrM7/

But, It is worth noting, that the point of this closure is to prevent multiple callbacks from getting stacked against some object. It is a really nice closure though that enables you to make sure that the last event triggered will be the one that gets acted on. I use this technique a lot to prevent flickering, or unwanted mouse out events during ie redraws.

Comment: Preventing multiple callbacks from getting stacked against some object is exactly what I'm looking to prevent, but I've got multiple objects that I want to prevent this against. Is using new the ideal way, or should I fundamentally alter the delay closure code I have?

Comment: You are wrong. Your code is incorrect. First, you are calling `delay` with no arguments (so you get calls of `setTimeout` with `undefined` arguments). Second, you write `delayManagerOne(firstCallback, 200)` - what should this do? Are you sure, you understand closures? If your code would be correct, you are still using the same `closured` variable `timer`.

Comment: With a closure this compact I don't think that you will encounter any performance benefits from recoding it. You don't actually need the new in this case, since you are actually returning a new function each time you call delay when you say return function() {}, so just var delayManagerOne = delay(); should work fine. delay() is really a generator here.

Comment: @orangutancloud: I do not want to offend you and challenge your programming skills. But you code is wrong. `timer` is not a member of `delay` here, it is closured. So anyway you cannot create new instance of `timer` var using code from question. And you cannot give `delay` 0 arguments.

Comment: @artyon.stv You are correct, I read the code too quickly. delay is actually an anonymous function while I had read it as a generator.

Comment: @artyon.stv I have edited the code and the closure to be a generator for a delay manager, should work but I have not actually tested it

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
Delay = function(callback, ms) {
    this.callback = callback;
    this.ms = ms;
};

Delay.prototype = {
    timer: -1,

    restart: function() {
        if (this.timer != -1) clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.callback, this.ms);
    }
};

var delay1 = new Delay(callback1, 100);
var delay2 = new Delay(callback2, 100);

// on some event1
delay1.restart();

// on some event2
delay2.restart();
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TF9Tw/1/

Answer (score 0):

The closure holds state that persists between calls of the inner function. In this case it is used so there is only one timeout at a time. If you want multiple timeouts available at a time you may just write

```
setTimeout(callback, ms);
```

edit:

For your example, the best solution would be to make an object like this

```
function DelayManager(){}
DelayManager.prototype.timer = 0;
DelayManager.prototype.delay = function(callback, ms) {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);             
  this.timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);   
}
someDelayManager = new DelayManager();
```

Where instead of someDelayManager you would use a member variable of some object unique per input element. To add a delay you would then call.

```
someDelayManager.delay(callback, ms);
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how can I write a reusable delay function then? For example, for keypress buffering, I only want to execute a callback when no key has been pressed for 200ms, necessitating the use of clearTimeout each time a key is pressed. I don't want to keep track of the ID, call clearTimeout, and then call setTimeout all over the place.